# Service Temporarily Unavailable Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

My application was working fine yesterday. I started my PC today. When I tried to start Magento I got this error message.

> Service Temporarily Unavailable
>
> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

I am not even able to open the admin page or see any sort of errors on the page. If I visit any URL of my Magento site I am getting the above output. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Is Magento running on a web server online or on your local computer? What are your environment details (web server, PHP, etc)? Did you recently add any extensions? Is any part of the page loading or is what you posted (literally) everything that's on the page?

Comment: Thanks Matthew. Its On Local, I am using Ubuntu and Xampp.. I tried to install magic zoom yesterday but that was not Installed , it was showing an error Can't connect to site try again later..

Answer (score 370, accepted):

Check if there is a file called **maintenance.flag** and if so **delete it**.

> **Magento 1.x** : maintenance.flag file is in : *magento root directory*

> **Magento 2.x** : maintenance.flag file is in : *var folder*

When Magento is performing certain tasks it temporarily creates this file. Magento checks for its existence and if it's there will send users to the page you described.

It's supposed to automatically delete this file when done processing whatever task it was doing, but I've experienced occasions where something went wrong and it failed to delete it.

Comment: I've faced the same problem after unsuccessful install of a module from magento connect. Deleting the file worked.

Comment: Where is `maintenance.flag` file ?

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com  It would be in the root folder of your magento website. But it will only be there if the site is stuck in maintenance mode. Under normal operations this file won't exist.

Comment: the flag in in `/var/www/html/magento/maintenance.flag` (centOS + apache server)

Comment: happening in Ubuntu VM but no flag file

Comment: What if there is **no** maintenance.flag file?

Comment: If you're not seeing a maintenance.flag file it could mean the error has become cached at some level. Delete all the files in the magento cache folder. If that doesn't work, you may have other cache you need to clear such as memcache or APC if you're using either of those.

Answer (score 12):

Simply delete the `maintenance.flag` file in root folder and then delete the files of cache folder and session folder inside `var/` folder.

Answer (score 11):

Now in new version **magento2** on Generate error Service Temporarily Unavailable.

```
Remove maintenance.flag
```

From this path which is changed `magento2/var/maintenance.flag`.

Also

```
$ rm maintenance.flag
```

Comment: for us it was `magento2/var/.maintenance.flag`

Answer (score 9):

To fix [Service Temporarily Unavailable Magento 2](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/service-temporarily-unavailable-magento.html), you should:

- Delete a file called `var/.maintenance.flag` in Magento root folder
- Remove Magento cache if any: `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue but have not found the maintenance.flag file in my Magento root.
I simply deleted cache and sessions files and all worked again.

Comment: I had to delete both sessions and cache files to get it to worked, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to follow these steps:

1. Go to magento root directory via cPanel/FTP
2. In case of Magento1, you will find **maintenance.flag** and delete it
3. In case of Magento2, delete **var/maintenance.flag**

Answer (score 2):

go to your website via `FTP/Cpanel`, find  `maintenance.flag` and remove

Comment: It seems that the question had already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8275318

Answer (score 2):

In Magento 2 You have to remove file located in /var/.maintenance.flag - just realized that after some searching, so i shall share.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this thing:

Go to **http://localhost/magento/downloader** url. Here I am running the magento store on my localhost. Now you can login to magento connect manager and uninstall the extension which you installed previously.

Hope this works !!!!!

Thanks.

Comment: Kind of overkill to remove a module just because it left behind a `maintenance.flag` file. Manually clear the cache, remove `maintenance.flag` and see if you can log into the admin panel to finish module installation.

Answer (score 1):

If you run into this problem (like I did) and NO maintenance.flag file exists anywhere, it's the Redis cache that's causing the problem; clear it.

I had to clear the Redis cache by contacting my hosting company and let them do it because I don't have access to that cache.

I figured this out using this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/55814/77803

Comment: Had same issue with Redis, using CM_Redis module the 503 is returned here  /app/code/local/Cm/RedisSession/Model/Session.php - I had some ConcurrentConnectionsExceededException so I increased the max_concurrency number without clearing the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Check the root folder of your Magento installation directory .You will find maintenance.flag file, delete it and refresh the site .it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I happen all the time when you install a new plugin.
You just have to delete maintenance.flag file in your root directory

Answer (score -6):

If removing the flag shows service temporary unavailable.
Go to "http://localhost.com/downloader" and unisntall slider banner,BusinessDecision_Interaktingslider,lightbox2 and anotherone that I dont remember.