# Magento Service Temporarily Unavailable Error

Tags: magento

I have installed magento-1.6.2.0 on my system. I have also installed some free Magento themes from Magento Connect. After some time suddenly I get following error:

"Service Temporarily Unavailable  The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later."

And from that event my Magento is stoped working. even it is not redirecting to other pages. So, anybody has the solution for above problem, please reply.

Comment: Does "my system" mean `localhost`? If so, have you tried to restart your webserver yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Service Temporarily Unavailable Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102777/service-temporarily-unavailable-magento)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

delete `maintenance.flag` file form your installation root.