# Magento sites showing blank frontend and backend

Tags: magento, amazon-web-services

I have 3 magento sites in a single server:  `www.site1.com`, `demo.site1.com`, `site2.com`.  All 3 magento sites were working fine.

Then, all of a sudden, `site1.com`'s frontend and backend showed blank.  Now `demo.site1`'s frontend is showing blank, and admin panel is working fine.  `site2.com` is working fine for both frontend and backend.

Why these sites are showing blank in frontend and backend?  We are using amazon server, with only 60% space used.

Comment: Any error displayed in frontend or exception.log file ?

Comment: nothing was displaying. after renamed local.sample.xml to local.xml now site displaying. but some menus are relocated in frontend.... 
 
in admin panel, some menus are not displaying

Comment: You say this happened "all of the sudden" -- can you expand on that? Surely, someone or some process changed **something**, hardware, software, settings.... something changed, or the functionality of the server/code would not have changed. Try to whittle this down to at least eliminate possibilities, it is very hard for anyone outside your organization to assess what went wrong, given the details you've provided.

Comment: I've joined the separated sentances into, I think, reasonable paragraphs, to imrpvoe readability.  Also removed the server tag, I don't think it adds anything here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete maintainance. flag file or rename it.... it's present tin root of the magento site : [Service Temporarily Unavailable Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102777/service-temporarily-unavailable-magento)