# Hyperlinks are showing path in Magento

Tags: html, css, magento, hyperlink

Out of the blue, the Magento site was displaying ["service temporarily unavailable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102777/service-temporarily-unavailable-magento). So, I deleted `maintenance.flags` file and the site came back, but now all of the header links on the main page and some sub pages are showing the paths on all hyperlinks: 
[image]

I have not changed anything prior to either of these issues and I have no idea how to fix this... I do have a template path helper, but what could cause this and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this in your skin/frontend/default/default/css/home/css/blueprint/print.css :

```
a:link:after, a:visited:after {content:" (" attr(href) ")";font-size:90%;}
```

remove it and it will work as expected

Comment: Thank you!! How does something like this happen? How can I prevent it from happening again?

Comment: np, the reason can be anything really, won't speculate